# Specifying image size when converting HTML to docx

Tags: docx, pandoc

I am using `Pandoc` to convert HTML to DOCX format. Everything works fine, but the resulting images are too big. If I resize them in input HTML nothing changes. I could resize the images with imagemagick, but they would be (more) blurry so this is a last resort.

Is it possible to specify "zoom level" for the images in Pandoc output document?

Also, if someone has a better converter which produces standalone DOC, DOCX or ODT that would help too... (my problem with `unoconv` is that it does not embed images, resulting document just references them - at least I couldn't find a way to do it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your images are appearing at 133% the size you expect, then the explanation is here:
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/834.  As explained there, you can use ImageMagick to set the DPI to 96 in the image files; this won't make them blurry.